# How to add border to div using Bootsrap CSS

Tags: css, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to add border and make the grid even, but the box size is varying on both boxes.

My HTML code:

```
<div class="col-md-2  hvr-grow-shadow" >
    <div class="widget">
        <div class="widget-controls">
            <span class="refresh-content"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></span>
        </div>
        <div  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="click" class="mini-stats cliente-sky ">
            <span class="sky-skin" >
                <p margin-top="15px;" style="margin-top: 15px;">1.5%</p>
            </span>
            <h5>C3 All Servers </h5>
            <h5> 2/2339</h5>
            <p>OVERALL SERVERS DOWN: 36</p>
            <button type="button" class="btns  red-skin btns-bot sml-btn sml-radius">Goal 2%</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2  hvr-grow-shadow" >
    <div class="widget">
        <div class="widget-controls cliente-sky">
            <span class="refresh-content"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></span>
        </div>
        <div  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="mini-stats ">
            <span class="purple-skin">
                <p margin-top="15px;" style="margin-top: 15px; color:white">1.4%</p>
            </span>
            <h5>CERTIFIED HP SERVER</h5>
            <h5>2/1891</h5>
            <p>OVERALL HP SERVERS DOWN: 26
            <p>
                <button type="button" class="btns  sky-skin btns-bot sml-btn sml-radius">Goal: 2%</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can someone help me achieve this?

Comment: Which `<tag>` are you trying to make bordered? is it the divs with `class ="hvr-grow-shadow"`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply .. Yes I am trying to make the border to this tag  <div class="col-md-2  hvr-grow-shadow" > and I am having 15 grid like this and every grid sizes are not even... I want to make border and all the grid looks same size.

Comment: Can you please post the css file?

Answer (score 0):

The reason the boxes are sized differently is because your tags are mismatched in the second box. Change:

```
    <p>OVERALL HP SERVERS DOWN: 26
    <p>
    <button type="button" class="btns  sky-skin btns-bot sml-btn sml-radius">Goal: 2%</button>
</div>
```

to:

```
    <p>OVERALL HP SERVERS DOWN: 26</p>
    <button type="button" class="btns  sky-skin btns-bot sml-btn sml-radius">Goal: 2%</button>
</div>
```

As for adding a border, it should be simple with CSS. Don't forget to set box-sizing properly or your borders may make things appear off again.

```
.hvr-grow-shadow {
    /* Border Stuff here, example:
     * border: 1px solid black;
     */
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```